# Import Arcpy Module Failing - PyScripter

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcpy, pyscripter

I am trying to use PyScripter however I can import certain modules however I am unable to successfully import the arcpy library.

I have tried configuring the Environment Variables PYTHONPATH without any success. I know I'm missing something with the the correct path to the python executable.

Thanks for your assistance in advance

The Desktop10.8pth references the following

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.8\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.8\ArcPy
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.8\ArcToolBox\Scripts
```

**Pyscripter is returning the following**

```
import arcpy
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcpy'

**IDLE Shell is returning**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in 
import arcpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcpy'

[Enviromental Varibles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDXUp.png)
[Program Files 86 to ArcGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLdZG.png)

[Pyscripter Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5tDz.png)

[Pyscripter Path Additional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlPot.png)

[Python Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEzQZ.png)
[Python27](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0USL.png)

Answer (score 1):

The message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcpy'` comes from whatever pythonx.y you are running.  Do you have more than one python installed on your system?  If so, the common error is to install something for one python and try to import it with another.

What you call the 2.7 structure shows `Python39-32`.  Does arcpy run with that version?

If you are trying to run arcpy with python x.y, the pythonx.y directory `Lib/site-packages/` must contain the arcpy package or a `.pth` file pointing to its location.  Is `Desktop10.8pth` a typo version of `Desktop10.8.pth`.  If so, then one of the directories, most likely the one ending in `ArcPy` must contain either an `arcpy` package directory or an `arcpy.py` file.